# Intersection points of two circles in c++

Tags: c++, collision-detection

Let define a circle in 2D:

```
struct Vec2D
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

// Assume dot, normalize, length, sum, subtract, and scale to exist.

struct Circle2D
{
    Vec2D center;
    float radius;
};
```

Given two circles, it is needed to determine the 0, 1 or 2 intersection points between the circles:

```
bool circleVsCircleIntersection( const Circle& a, const Circle& b, 
    std::array<std::optional<Vec2D>,2>& intersPos);
```

**How to determine the 0, 1 or 2 intersection points of the circles in C++?**

Comment: Start with: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39561/finding-the-intersecting-points-on-two-circles

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the intersection points ? If not then this is a maths question rather than a programming question.

Comment: @UlfLindback: The question of how one would find the intercepts mathematically doesn't necessarily coincide with how one should do it in code.  It's not uncommon for a mathematically-"simpler" formula, computed using double precision, to yield results inferior to what a more complicated formula could yield even using float precision.  A Google search on the subject turns up many mathematical descriptions, but I didn't see any code examples that addressed the issue of precision, so I don't know if any of the results I saw were very good.

Comment: Compare the sum or difference of the radii to the distance between the centers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a circles center and it's radius
you can setup an equation like

```
(x-x1)²+(y-y1)²=r1²
```

you can do this for both circles

```
I  x²-2xx1+x1²+y²-yy1+y1²=r1²
II x²-2xx2+x2²+y²-yy2+y2²=r2²
```

then you can insert II in I and there you go :)

Comment: If this is done by solving the quadratic II for y in terms of x, the computation is quite painful. Much better to subtract I and II to get rid of the quadratic terms first. And as only the number of solution is requested, there is a simpler solution.