# Circle to circle intersection

Tags: c++, c

I have searched Google and could find circle to circle intersection, but I did not find any way to tell if the intersection is from left, right, top, or bottom.

Can you please show me how is that done in C or C++?

I did try this, but the sides it output is wrong..

```
if ( ((dx*dx) + (dy*dy)) < radii * radii) {



    if (Circle2Position.x < Circle1Position.x) {
       // code |= LEFT;



    } else if (Circle2Position.x > Circle1Position.x+Circle1.width) {
       // code |= RIGHT;


    }

    if (Circle2Position.y < Circle1Position.y) {
       // code |= BOTTOM;


    } else if (Circle2Position.y  > Circle1Position.y  + Circle1.height) {

       // code |= TOP;


    }

        }
```

Comment: google is your friend: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20find%20intersection%20of%20two%20circles

Comment: That don't answer my question.

Comment: What did you try so far? How did it not work?

Comment: The mathematical procedure to detect an intersection between two circles is easily discoverable on Google (as @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz pointed out). Can you use that to also detect where the colision is from? Maybe using the coordinates of the centre of the circle? Or any data about the previous movement of these circles?

Comment: maybe will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727065/intersection-points-of-two-circles-in-c

Comment: What does "intersection from left" mean actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather a mathematical than a C++ specific problem. You can determine the quadrant using the vector `v = c1 - c2` which is the difference between the two circle centers `c1` and `c2`. Then, depending on the signs of `v`'s X and Y coordinates, you can say in which direction a circle is relative to another.

In C++, it can make sense to use existing vector classes depending on the amount of geometry-related code. What to suggest depends a bit on your project and its field...

Comment: width and height? Don't you use circles that have the same radius everywhere? :)

Comment: No. The circles size is not always the same :)

Comment: What I meant is: why width *and* height? That makes no sense for a circle which has *one* radius. Are we talking about an ellipsis?

Comment: True, i'm sorry. Can you show me simple based on circles radius? what side makes the intersection please

Comment: @TheOperator *Ellipsis* is "...", not a geometric figure.  ;-)